# Adding side by side divs confusion

Tags: html, css, styling

I always seems to get this simple HTML stuff wrong.  I am currently trying to add side by side divs in the middle of a page on this test page I made:

http://www.comehike.com/hiking_dev.php

The code I added was something like this:

```
<div style="width: 460px; float: left; ">
<strong>Test hello</strong>
</div>
<div style="width: 300px; float: right; ">
<strong>Test hello 2</strong>
</div>
```

I added `<strong>` tags so you can spot it on the page better.

But do you see there is text that appears there that reads like this "When considering the injury risk of any" - but that text is in the `<p>` tag below.  Why is it appearing there?

Is it better practice to wrap my 2 divs that I am trying to align, within another div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your two floating divs, add another empty div...

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

This will cause the two floating divs to push all subsequent content below them.  As you have it now, there is 200 pixels of empty space after the first div allowing the other content to simply wrap around it.

Increasing the width of the floating divs may not be desirable for your layout so `clear:both;` is most typical for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Surround those two divs in a parent div with overflow set to hidden.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="width: 460px; float: left; ">
    <strong>Test hello</strong>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 300px; float: right; ">
    <strong>Test hello 2</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

An alternative (as others have pointed out) is to use a third element:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

It's debatable as to which is better. Usually, either is just fine. Here's a post about the topic:
[Floated Child Elements: overflow:hidden or clear:both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648205/floated-child-elements-overflowhidden-or-clearboth)

Comment: Not needed, just a width issue.

Comment: I disagree. Divs set to float side by side should always be in a container. Either that or the next element should have clear:both; set. Without this all kinds of funk will happen.

Comment: That makes sense and I normally practice that, I was just saying as a fix.

Comment: I prefer `clear:both;` as it allows content to determine height rather than hiding any overflow.

Comment: @Sparky672 actually overflow:hidden will cause it to expand to fit height of floated elements. Exact same effect.

Comment: @tybro0103:  Interesting, however, ... 1.  it just _seems_ counterintuitive and 2.  you need a parent container.  (+1 for the link.)

Comment: @Sparky672 I can see that. Personally, I think the fact that it's called overflow:hidden is misleading (seems like it would do something else... it is a little hackish). Either way though, you'll need either a parent or a sibling. I've found that In almost all cases I already have a parent anyways.

Comment: In fact, in my global css I usually add div {overflow:hidden;}. Then, I never need to worry about it except in the case where I actually want overflow to show, which is rare.

Answer (score 2):

You'll either need to add a div below your two divs with `clear:both;` as others have suggested, or you could add `clear:both;` to the following `<p>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have an entire page width of `960px`. You're combined div widths are `760px` (400+300). If you add 200px to the second div you should be fine.

**Edit:** Because of padding, you can increase either of the divs by `150px` and be fine.

Comment: Widths for such things are always bound to change, whether with containing layout or the content itself. Not to mention, depending on doctypes, different browsers calculate total widths differently. Fixing it this way will require lots of future refixes. Use the surrounding overflow:hidden; or the third element clear:both;