# 100% percentage total flowing over the next line

Tags: html, css

this is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Loaz7gcu/

I have three inputs which should fit on one line, equaling 100% but instead one sits on the next line. I have cleared all the margins and padding but still no luck. What am I doing wrong here?

My example CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
.one {
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 10%
}
.two {
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 10%
}
.three {
    width: 20%
}
```

Comment: try setting them in a container div and use float properties on them

Comment: It's math. 3*30 + 2*10 is above 100%: http://jsfiddle.net/Loaz7gcu/2/.

Comment: @DOCASAREL it's (30+10) + (30+10) + 20 = 100

Comment: I know it's math, it does equal 100%....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it by using `box-sizing: border-box;` and `display:inline-block;` to `input` and use `font-size:0px;` to `div` for remove the white-space and then set `font-size: 16px;` to input.

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Loaz7gcu/11/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div style="width: 100%; font-size:0px;">
    <input class="one">
    <input class="two">
    <input class="three">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:16px;
}
.one {
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 10%
}
.two {
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 10%
}
.three {
    width: 20%
}
```

Comment: Or.. **float the inputs** or remove the whitespace from the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you should take care about:

1. In inline flow, there's a [whitespace between inline level elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)
2. UAs apply a border to input elements by default which causes the total width exceeds `100%` of width of the container.

That being said, you could float the `input`s and give [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to achieve the goal:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/Loaz7gcu/13/)**

```css
input {
    float: left;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And don't forget to [clear the float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564106/best-practice-for-css-clear-or-overflow) at the end of the container.

Comment: You might also want to consider:  [Which method of ‘clearfix’ is best?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best/1633170#1633170)

Comment: yesterday I learned about how to remove the whitespace between inline-block elements and today I used it. lol :)

Comment: @MaryMelody It shows that you're on the right track! keep on.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use `display: flex` in your `div` container:

**html**

**css**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
.one {
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 10%
}
.two {
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 10%
}
.three {
    width: 20%
}
div {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Loaz7gcu/24/)

**Ref**

> The flex CSS property is a shorthand property specifying the ability
>   of a flex item to alter its dimensions to fill available space. Flex
>   items can be stretched to use available space proportional to their
>   flex grow factor or their flex shrink factor to prevent overflow.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this

```
input{
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

because you have 100% + the border left and right for each element...so that's 100% + 6px;
border-box will make the border to be inside the div not outside of it

and also because of the whitespace between the elements you have to get dirty with the inputs

either add them on the same line or :

```
   <input><!--
--><input><!--
--><input>
```

by adding comments such as this

Comment: @JamesWillson, this works, but combined with j08691's answer about white spaces... http://jsfiddle.net/Loaz7gcu/15/