# css background-color troubles

Tags: html, css

I'm updating a header on a site, and the whole header should have a light gray background.  To achieve that, I figured I could simply set the background-color of the overall header div to gray (E7E7E7), but somehow I'm getting a white space in the middle of it, and I can't seem to select/find the the overall div with Firebug.

The overall div is the one with class="header", and the page is http://www.momentumnow.biz/mn/index.shtml.

Would you please let me know what I need to do to get rid of this white space in the header (and what I'm doing wrong here).  Note you need to make your browser window wide.  I want the purple flash on the right to stay toward the right-hand side of the page as the person makes the page wider.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `clear your float` like this:

```
div.header {
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
    min-width: 1010px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Write now there are `three floated child DIV's` inside you `.header DIV` which need to have `clear`. So, write `overflow:hidden` in your `.header`.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep.  I'm confused (obviously! :-).  I see I messed up doing the clear outside the header div (which I just moved).  Can you expand on what overflow:hidden does, why it is a substitute for a clear?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'll ask one more question if I may.  Is there a way to get that center section "Inspiring Movement..." to float and sit half way between the two flash pieces, but using a minimum padding/margin on both sides?

Comment: for your second question you have to change your mark like this http://jsfiddle.net/9R8SP/

Comment: for your first question may be it's better you can check these links http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648205/floated-child-elements-overflowhidden-or-clearboth

Comment: Ok, will do.  Thanks very much for that additional code you gave to center the middle section.  Have a nice night/day. :-)

Comment: @Sandeep - Are you online by chance?  I made the centering changes you pointed, but the middle section still isn't centering.  Do  you see what the problem is?

Comment: remove float from your div.headerCenter & give overflow:hidden to it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear your floats. If you inspect `header` with Chrome tools you will see that it has a height of 0. This is because you floated the internal elements (pulling them out of normal flow). Just clear them and your container will again have height. Or assign a height.

Comment: Thanks. Since you guys are so fast at this (thanks BTW), can I ask you, how can I position that Affiliate Care Members link, a couple pixels higher than it is now.  I gave it 4px of margin at the bottom, but it doesn't raise up, and I need to keep the header to no more than 120px high (purple flash piece is 100px high).  Thanks.

Comment: @Ray - assign a negative margin to the top. Margins are like extra space around the edges of the element. Adding a bottom margin just makes it push stuff below it down.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  The negative margin did it (and I see what you are saying about putting the margin at the bottom).  But why didn't this element jam right up against the flash piece above it?  Do I have some margins or padding I'm not seeing?

Comment: ... Looks like the object tag had some margin or padding somehow.  When I added a class to clear those out, I was able to get rid of the negative margin.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="headerLeft">
   <div class="affiliate">
   <div class="headerRight">
   <div style="clear: both"></div> //add this 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just check that every thing in the div header or not and the inner con-taint must change there background color also when changing headers background color or else you make all con-taint above header should have the transparent background color so if you change hearders background it will reflect for other inner div and con-taints........