# Internal div Popping Out of Layout

Tags: html, css

I have a layout issue where the internal div "data" seems to be popping out of its containing div and showing outside. I've placed coloured borders around the bottom picture and the problem I'm having is the yellow text should be in the white box, but it's not. Anyone know what the issue is here I'm currently stumped. I've tried using clear:both but it didn't seem to work.

[image]

```
.whiteContainer
        {
        border: 1px dotted red;
            margin:3%;
            background: white;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }
#display
        {
        border: 1px dotted green;
            margin:3%;
        }
.header
        {
        border: 1px dotted blue;
            float:left;
        }
.data
        {
        border: 1px dotted yellow;
            float:right;
        }
```

HTML portion:

```
<div class="whiteContainer">
    <div id="display">
        <div class='header'>Program Name: </div>
        <br />
        <div class='data'>
            Strategic Project Grants
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### EDIT:

removing the `<br/>` gives me the results of http://jsfiddle.net/SgEMc/ which still pop the content of the blue and yellow elements out of the green one, which is not what I want. I can't specify an exact height for the white element because the amount of program names displayed in the white space will vary. I will also need the break statement later on as I would need something along where Header is displayed followed by a `<br/>` and then centered text. All this needs to be inside the white container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the parent container of the data (id=display) to "overflow:hidden" or "overflow:auto". It will force the parent to conform to the shape of the floats. There are actually quite a few techniques to achieve your goal. See [CSS Tricks - All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/), there is a section about clearing floats.

Answer (score 3):

The br is the reason for the missallignment, but you need to clear the float. put a clearfix style on the white container

http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

or add a clearing element after your floating elements if you don't mind the extra markup.

```
<br style="clear:both" />
```

after your data div.

then if either wraps, the container will stretch to suit the content.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SgEMc/2/ still makes the yellow content pop out of the green div.

Comment: your fiddle is wrong: the br needs to be after the data div, see http://jsfiddle.net/SgEMc/3/

Comment: I wanted the break before the data portion, header on one line and data on the other where I would eventually centre the data. I needed everything to stay in the green dotted box which is what I was having trouble with. Apparently overflow:auto; did the trick, however your answer was instrumental in fixing the other portion of the layout that followed, so a deserved upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `<br />` tag in your code.

You may also want to slightly alter your CSS. This is what I used in the following jsFiddle:

```
.whiteContainer {
    border: 1px dotted red;
    margin:3%;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    height:50px;
    }
#display {
    overflow:auto;
    border: 1px dotted green;
    margin:4px;
    }
.header {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    float:left;
    }
.data {
    border: 1px dotted yellow;
    float:right;
    }
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/h4tPD/)**.

Comment: overflow:auto; seems to make the formatting work! In comparison to http://jsfiddle.net/SgEMc/ where the elements were outside the green box, http://jsfiddle.net/h4tPD/3/ keeps them inside. I am still not sure why though, I would have imagined there would be a problem with the float but I don't get how the overflow is the solution.

Comment: I found this years ago and it has come in handy many times: http://www.sitepoint.com/simple-clearing-of-floats/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<br>`

http://jsfiddle.net/SgEMc/

Answer (score 0):

remove the "br" betwen your floated elements and add overflow: hidden; to #display.

see this:
http://jsfiddle.net/HOLYCOWBATMAN/updZW/

Comment: overflow:hidden vs clear both : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648205/floated-child-elements-overflowhidden-or-clearboth